# Disk times out with I/O Errors while using ddrescue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, disk-utility, ddrescue

I am trying to use ddrescue on Ubuntu 19.04 to image a failing external hard disk. There is a primary Windows NTFS partition of 220GB and a secondary Recovery NTFS partition of 14GB. ddrescue is able to image the latter just fine, but when used to image the larger partition it slows to a crawl. Checking dmesg shows that the system is timing out for every I/O error. Is there any way to disable this timeout so that ddrescue will finish in a reasonable amount of time?

dmesg output:

```
[188659.123829] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2176 flags 0
[188841.586225] sd 7:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[188841.586235] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[188841.586237] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[188841.586238] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit communication CRC error (Ultra-DMA/32)
[188841.586241] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 80 00
[188841.586242] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 5888 flags 0
[189021.915161] sd 7:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[189021.915191] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[189021.915193] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[189021.915195] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit communication CRC error (Ultra-DMA/32)
[189021.915197] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 1d 80 00 00 80 00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that most of the I/O errors are at the beginning of the partition where Windows was using it when the disk crashed. While ddrescue was reading these sectors I disabled the timeout by running `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/timeout`
 as root.

This reduced the timeout to 6 seconds (Ubuntu multiplies the timeout value by 6 for some reason.)

After the erroneous sectors were copied, I increased the timeout back to 30 seconds so the copy didn't timeout because the disk was slow.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to rescue data from a defective piece of kit – the reasonable time for 220GB is measured in weeks or months, not hours.

That said, the GNU version of ddrescue allows you these settings:

- `-a` (in bytes/s) is the minimum read rate considered good. If throughput falls below this threshold, a chunk will be skipped
- `-K` – the size of the chunk to skip on each read error

This way you can pick the low hanging fruits first and only proceed to the extra-slow reads in a later pass.

Comment: Why does the first partition read so slowly while the Recovery partition reads at a quick 30Mb/s?

Comment: Because the surface defects in the disk are not spread equally - the recovery partition is almost never touched, so has a much lesser chance (by orders of magnitude) to develop them.